# The world is brutal and cold

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

Steal my prefix and perform a sacrifice.
Steal my suffix and venture all over ice.
Steal my infix and a shove from fatality.
Steal my whole and forget a part of me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer may be:

> **SKILL**

*Steal my prefix and perform a sacrifice.*

> Remove ('steal') the prefix **S** to make **KILL** - an action necessary to *perform* an animal or human *sacrifice*.

*Steal my suffix and venture all over ice.*

> Remove the suffix **LL** to make **SKI** - to move *over ice* or snow.

*Steal my infix and a shove from fatality.*

> Remove the infix **K** and you are left standing on a **SILL** - one wrong movement (or indeed a *shove*) and it's potentially a *lethal* and long way down from the window ledge...

*Steal my whole and forget a part of me.*

> Remove all the letters - i.e. lose a **SKILL** - and you *forget* how to do a particular task...

<sub>PS As for the title, I don't think this is relevant to the word itself - instead it's purely to set the tone for the rhyme: 'brutal' in the sense of a human/animal sacrifice or a fatal shove, and 'cold' with the imagery of ice...</sub>